# What is the meaning of this sentence "Let me be real for a second"?

Tags: meaning

Recently I saw the sentence

> Let me be real for a second.

What does it mean?

Comment: 'Let me [stop fantasising / waffling {talking about trivia} and] seriously address the main issue/s / problem/s.'

Comment: thank you @EdwinAshworth. I saw this sentence in video "Frankie the Dinosaur has a message for Humanity" what UNDP uploaded.

Comment: Connected with similar sayings like "get real".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means step out of the usual social politeness conventions, and be bluntly realistic.

http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/be-real

It includes a warning that what the person is about to say might be unusually blunt, might hurt the listener's feelings or surprise them.

Examples of possible next sentences after the sentence referenced in the question:

Let me be real for a second.

- That outfit really isn't doing you any favors
- This party is boring and your guests are going to start leaving unless something is done
- What you said last Tuesday really bothered me, and I need to know what you were referring to
- In high school, most of the time I told you I was in the library, that wasn't where I was.

Comment: Good answer! I would argue that, as an extension of that usage, it's gaining a usage that equates simply to "Let me extend an intimacy or vulnerability that this conversation hasn't warranted previously." E.g., "Let me be real for a second, I haven't slept in two days."

Comment: I agree! And another related extension - in a relationship between two people who are constantly joking with each other, play-acting, verbally teasing each other etc.. it can mean - "for once, take this next thing seriously. It may sound like I'm joking, but I'm not."

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the context, as *real* has too many connotations to pin down, but the general sentiment seems to imply "realistic".

> Let's be realistic for a second, sentences don't mean anything. In reality, people do the meaning.

This simply stuff that belongs with https://ell.stackexchange.com/